# While using audio unit's VoiceProcessingIO recorder callback is giving voice cuts in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios5

I m developing VoIP client. I am using Audio unit for player and recorder.
To avoid Echo I m using VoiceProcessingIO as subtype. While doing this recorder is giving abrupt voice cut while recording continuously. This is the working fine in iOS4. It seems bug in iOS5. Is there any other property to set?

Comment: I am experiencing the similar symptom.  Any resolution?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, as it turned out there is a setting called kAUVoiceIOProperty_VoiceProcessingQuality that you can set to adjust the level of suppression to apply to the Audio Units.    Here is the link to Apple's article.  [Technical Q&A QA1683](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#qa/qa1683/_index.html)